# Suppose $W(t)$ is a standard Brownian motion. Calculate the probability of $1<W(1)<W(3)−1$

Tags: probability, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

I've tried calculating it as $Pr[W(3)-W(1)<-1] + 1 - Pr[W(3)-W(1)<1]
=0.23975 + 1- 0.76025
=47.95\%$

But, this doesn't seem to be correct. Please help

Answer (score 4):

This is about the independence of $W(1)$ and $W(3)-W(1)$. 
$$
\begin{align}
P(W(3)-W(1)>1 \ \mathrm{and} \ W(1)>1)&=P(W(3)-W(1)>1) P(W(1)>1)\\
&=P(W(2)>1)P(W(1)>1)\\
&=P(\sqrt 2 W(1)>1) P(W(1)>1)\\
&=\left(1-\Phi(\frac1{\sqrt 2}) \right) (1-\Phi(1))
\end{align}
$$
where 
$$
\Phi(x) = \frac 1{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^x e^{-\frac{t^2}2} dt.
$$

Comment: I had not thought of applying independence!Brilliant, many thanks!